# How to get the Session in a Razor template

Tags: razormediator

I would like to get the session in a Razor Template.  I have tried TridionHelper.Session and also Session and _session with no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The Session in Tom.Net is available on most objects as '.Session'.  I got a nice hint from [Frank Taylor's blog post](http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2013/05/14/make-a-debugging-tbb-for-tridion-2011-using-razor-mediator/) where he used Component.TridionObject.Session and then I was also able to use myStructureGroup.Session.